# Facing Issue in Join method in thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a doubt that I am creating few threads inside a loop and it will call the run method that I had implemented . I have doubt that though I have written `t.join` without completing its run method main thread is moving forward and executing later steps. How to stop this ?

```
for(int j=1;j<=iteration;j++){
    Thread t=null;
    System.out.println("Starting Iteration-"+j);
    for(int i=1;i<=totalNumberOfUsers;i++) {
        t=new Thread(new CasLoadTest());
        t.setName("User"+i);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep((long) (delayPeriod*1000));
    }
    t.join();
    for(Map.Entry<String,Long> map:latencyMap.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(map.getKey()+"-"+map.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("Iteration"+j+"-->Max:"+Collections.max(latencyMap.values()));
    System.out.println("Iteration"+j+"-->Min:"+Collections.min(latencyMap.values()));
    double temp=(double)(lastUserLoggedIn-firstUserLoggedIn)/1000;
    System.out.println("Iteration"+j+"-->Total Number of Users Logged In (Users\\Sec)--"+totalNumberOfUsers/temp);

    latencyMap.clear();
    threadCount = totalNumberOfUsers;
    count = 0;
    Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

Comment: you are only waiting for the `last` thread to termintae

Comment: Yes . How to modify it to make all threads created in loop till then main thread should wait ? Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all Threads that you have created in a list. Then you can wait for all to exit their operation before going on with your main method.

```
ArrayList<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<>(); // create a list of all Threads
for(int i=1;i<=totalNumberOfUsers;i++) {
    t=new Thread(new CasLoadTest());
    allThreads.add(t); // add new Thread to list
    ...
}
...
// wait for all Threads to end before executing next code
for(Thread thread : allThreads)
    thread.join();
```

Comment: Thanks . Thats what i required